# How can I set a cell on the iPhone as a custom color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

I am trying to add custom color like how we do in HTML:

```
<body bgcolor=#ffffff> </body>.
```

Can we have a similar kind of custom color combination for showing in cells on iPhones?

```
cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor whiteColor]; but instead of whiteColor wanna use #ffffff.
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIColor [colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a).   Colors are 0.0 to 1.0, something like this for bright red:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0 blue:0 alpha1];
```

For a color such as "808182" it would be:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255.0f green:129/255.0f blue:130/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Comment: What will be the colorWithRed for "0092dd" ? lets say for an alphabet dd as an example.

Comment: Convert each of the two hex digits to decimal, 00 is 0 for the red, 92 becomes 9*16+2 for green, dd becomes 13*16+13 for blue.  But those are on a 0..255 range which is why I divided them by 255.0f above to get them into a 0.0 to 1.0 range.  The math is left as an exercise for the OP ;-)