# How can i set a light blue back ground color to my UITableView cell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uicolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a cell on the iPhone as a custom color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506042/how-can-i-set-a-cell-on-the-iphone-as-a-custom-color)

i need to set a light orange back ground color to my UITableView cell.so please any one help me to do it.i used the following code to get green color.so please help me to do it.

need UIColor *myColor = "**light orange color**" also if you can UIColor *myColor = "**light blue color"**

Answer (score 8):

You need RGB color values.

Then:
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 180.0/255.0 green: 238.0/255.0 blue:180.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];

Keep in mind that the values you enter for red green and blue are based on a max value of 1.0.  Normal RGB numbers are based on a max of 255 so you need to divide regular values by 255 to get the right values.

Answer (score -1):

Why not set your color to "clear" and use Photoshop (or some other editor" to make the color and style that you want?

```
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```