# Convert a color from colorWithRGBA to colorWithWhite

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicolor

I've been using a hex calculator to convert hex values to RGB values ( #666 = 102/102/102 and so on).

It seems I can't use this with UIColor though, `[UIColor colorWithRed:102 green:102 blue:102 alpha: 1.0]` just seems to return white (tried 60 too). If I use [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.6 alpha:1.0] I get a dark color- so how can I convert a value like 102/102/102 into a colorWithWhite value?

A way I've tried is to take that value and divide by 255, so 102/255 = 0.4 so I set my `colorWithWhite` value to 0.4. Is that accurate?

Comment: `[UIColor colorWithRed:102 green:102 blue:102 alpha: 1.0]` won't work because each color must be from 0.0 to 0.1 and 102 it out of range.  You want 102/255.0 for each color.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5506134/1693173) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010540/1693173) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha`

Parameters:
red - The red component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

green - The green component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

blue - The blue component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

alpha - The opacity value of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

So to convert your RGB values to be between 0.0 and 1.0, do #/255

Edit: In response to your edit, yes it's correct. But remember if you do that in code, you're doing integer division and you'll get 0. Make the 255 a float variable or use the constant 255.f

Comment: The question asks how to convert to `UIColor(white: , alpha: )` from RGB. Your answer does not specify it.